# AutoComplete not working in jsp

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp, autocomplete

I'm writing a small program for autocomplete in Java. And it is as below.

**Index.html**
    
    
    
    
    Autocomplete in java web application using Jquery and
        JSON

```
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h3>Autocomplete in java web application using Jquery and JSON</h3>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="search-container">
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <input type="text" id="search" name="search" class="search" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**autocompleter.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#search").autocomplete({
            source : function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url : "Controller",
                    type : "GET",
                    data : {
                        term : request.term
                    },
                    dataType : "json",
                    success : function(data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**DataDao.java**

```
package com.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataDao {
    private Connection connection;

    public DataDao() throws Exception {
        connection = DBUtility.getConnection();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getFrameWork(String frameWork) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        String data;
        try {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement("select * from StatusTable WHERE [case owner]  LIKE ?");
            ps.setString(1, frameWork + "%");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                data = rs.getString("case Owner");
                list.add(data);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

**DBUtility.java**

```
package com.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DBUtility {
    private static Connection connection = null;

    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        if (connection != null)
            return connection;
        else {
            // Store the database URL in a string
            String userName = "sa";
            String password = "T!ger123";
            String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://U0138039-TPD-A\\SQLEXPRESS;DatabaseName=TEST";

            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

            // set the url, username and password for the databse
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            return connection;
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.dao.DataDao;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        try {
            String term = request.getParameter("term");
            System.out.println("Data from ajax call " + term);

            DataDao dataDao = new DataDao();
            ArrayList<String> list = dataDao.getFrameWork(term);

            String searchList = new Gson().toJson(list);
            response.getWriter().write(searchList);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

When i run this program, in the textbox, there is no auto suggest dropdown seen.

I'm not sure if `rs.getString("case Owner");` is causing the problem (the space in the quotes).

Also I'm not sure since there is only one name of type(please refer to the below image), the dropdown doesn't appear.

please correct me on the above assumptions.

When i run `select * from StatusTable`, I get the below output in the below Image. 
[image]

I'm sorry for the red strike through, These are a bit confidential.

Please let me know where am i going wrong and how can i fix this.